# English pronunciation symbols – why so many systems?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I wanted to improve my English pronunciation. But I just realize that I cannot understand the symbols in my English dictionaries (including some online dictionaries). There are so many, just look at [this table](http://www.liquisearch.com/pronunciation_respelling_for_english/traditional_respelling_systems).

My first question is for my general culture. Why are there so many? And which system is used the most?

My second question concerning a website teaching the pronunciation: http://pronuncian.com/sounds
Do you know a dictionary (including online dictionary) using the same phonetic symbols?

Comment: Well because each dictionary was competing against each other to be sold and when their systems were first devised there was no universal system, each dictionary pretty much had its own system. However nowadays the I.P.A. system is a universally recognised method of pronouncing words in any language. While this is not used in most paper dictionaries, any online dictionary worth its salt gives an I.P.A. pronunciation for each word.

Comment: There are different systems for representing American and British English, because they are pronounced differently. The American English phonemic system is presented in [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/n5/mode/2up), which is available online free. The chart you point to in the question is of no value; ignore it. Just learn a [little phonetics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf).

Comment: After the response of John Lawler, I recognized that John's list has 14 vowels and the site http://pronuncian.com/sounds  have 15 vowels. A quick search on the Internet reveals that the number of vowels can go up to 20. It's unbelievable. That means people in some regions (or countries) can distinguish the language better than people in other regions, although the first ones maybe aren't native speakers.

Comment: Come back to the website http://pronuncian.com/sounds , I don't know this website is good for improving American English pronunciations. I have a doubt just because the number of vowels of this page  (15 vowels) is different the number in John's list (14 vowels). Could you please tell me if I can continue to use this website?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means that some regions use ***more*** vowels than other regions. For example, *cot* and *caught* are pronounced exactly the same in California, but have different vowels in New York and in England. And in much of England, *bared, beard, bed* and *bid* are distinguished by having four different vowels, while in most of the U.S., the difference between *bared* and *bed* is that *bared* has an /r/.

Comment: So if you're trying to represent the sounds of American English, you don't need more than 15 or so vowels because that's the number most Americans use.